# Article width in em becomes too narrow when not full lines

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I have a hobby website, with drupal 7 and time to time struggling with this:

I have set the Article width as max-width:35em;

it works well with most articles of such kind, except - some articles - are Verses/ Poetry - meaning the line width is never full 35em, but some 40-50% of this...

and what happens - the full article width shrinks to very narrow....

I expected - it would still be 35em min, and would leave white line endings, but I cannot find an easy solution...

(also - I don't want to set min-width or width, because there is another block on left and it would screw design on browser resize)

Update:
I'm adding Fiddle:
1. OK with long text https://jsfiddle.net/3kef5923/24/

```css
.ds-2col-stacked{}

.node{display: block;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-size: 1.125em;
margin-top: -.75em;}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-header{}
.ds-2col-stacked > .group-right
{padding-left: 15em;
width: 100%;
max-width: 34.722em;}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-left
{float: left;
max-width: 15em;}
```

```html
<div class="ds-2col-stacked node">

<div class="group-header">

</div>
<div class="group-left">
<p>
some short text here Left
</p>
</div>

<div class="group-right">
<p>
some Long text here right some Long text here right some Long text here right some Long text here right some Long text here right some Long text here right some Long text here right
</p>
</div>

</div>
```

2. Failing with short text https://jsfiddle.net/vsexzzt4/5/

```css
.ds-2col-stacked{}

.node{display: block;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-size: 1.125em;
margin-top: -.75em;}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-header{}
.ds-2col-stacked > .group-right
{padding-left: 15em;
width: 100%;
max-width: 34.722em;}

.ds-2col-stacked > .group-left
{float: left;
max-width: 15em;}
```

```html
<div class="ds-2col-stacked node">

<div class="group-header">

</div>
<div class="group-left">
<p>
some short text here Left
</p>
</div>

<div class="group-right">
<p>
some Long text 
</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: you can set  `width:100%` or any value you want with `max-width:35em;` for proper solution add any snippet or fiddle or link

Comment: I updated with Fiddle